# How to compute a product of all digits of a negative integer number or zero?

Tags: python

I need compute a product of all digits of an integer number. The [algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-to-calculate-product-of-digits-of-a-number/) is quit simple. One can see the implementation of the Python.

```
print("input number:")
n = int(input())
mult = 1
while (n!=0):
    mult = mult * (n % 10)
    n = n // 10
print("product is", mult)
```

**Question.** How to compute a product of all digits of a negative integer number or zero?

My attemp is

```
print("input number:")
m = int(input())
n = abs(m)
mult = 1
while (n!=0):
    mult = mult * (n % 10)
    n = n // 10
if (m==0):
    print("product is", 0)
elif (m>0):
    print("product is", mult)
else:
    print("product is", -mult)
```

I am looking for a solution without an additional variable.

Comment: if m == 0: ..... elif m == abs(m): print positive else print negative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if n is positive or negative. Based on that `mult` will be `1` or `-1`. The rest will be as normal.

```
print("input number:")
n = int(input())
mult = 1 if n==abs(n) else -1
n=abs(n)
while (n!=0):
    mult = mult * (n % 10)
    n = n // 10

print("product is", mult)
```

Alternate, you can use `math.prod` to calculate the product.

```
import math
print("input number:")
n = int(input())
mult = (1 if n==abs(n) else -1) * math.prod([int(i) for i in str(abs(n))])
print ('product is', mult)
```

This will give:

```
input number:
32
product is 6

input number:
-32
product is -6
```

If you want to use `functools.reduce`, then you can do.

```
from functools import reduce
print("input number:")
n = int(input())
mult = (1 if n==abs(n) else -1) * reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, [int(i) for i in str(abs(n))], 1)
print ('product is', mult)
```

Output will be:

```
input number:
32
product is 6

input number:
-32
product is -6

input number:
503
product is 0
```

Answer (score 1):

It is simple: 
Do it like this:

```
n = int(input("input number:"))
n1 = n

mult1 = 1
while n!=0:
 if n1 == 0:
  print("the product is",n)
 else:
  for i in str(n1):
    i = int(i)
    mult = i*mult1
    mult1 = mult
  print("product is:",mult)
 n = 0
```

Output:

input number:123456
720

I couldn't do the code for negative numbers.

Comment: OP is looking for a solution without the additional variable.